# How can i get the bgcolor of a treewalker textnode in javascript (in firefox)?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, dom

i wrote this function to get all textnodes of a HTML-Document:

```
function testit(root){
    w=document.createTreeWalker(root, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, null, false);
    a=[]
    while (n=w.nextNode()) {
        a.push(n);
        console.log(n)
    }
}
```

I would like to get the background and foreground color of the text, i'm pretty sure that i have to find these attributes somewhere in the parent nodes, but i have no idea how.

I never touched javascript in combination with DOM and firefox (and XUL etc.) so i would be very thankful for helpful links too, since i recognized that this topic isn't documented as good as python for example.

thanks for your constructive answers!

Answer (score 0):

Ok i've found out how to get the bgcolor and the color attribute of the parent element now by changing my code to this:

```
function testit(root){
    w=document.createTreeWalker(root, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, null, false);
    a=[]
    while (n=w.nextNode()) {
        a.push(n);
        console.log(n.textContent)
        console.log('bgcolor: '+window.getComputedStyle(n.parentElement).getPropertyValue('background-color'))
        console.log('color: '+window.getComputedStyle(n.parentElement).getPropertyValue('color'))
        console.log('------------')
    }
}
```

Is this a stable way to do this?

The returned bgcolor is sometimes 'transparent', is it right to say that in this case the color is automatic the bgcolor of ?